# ssis variable not evaluating

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a variable that concatenates a file path into a string , and i can't get it to evaluate the concatenation. when i display the value of the variable in a script task, i still see all the double quote marks (see below). I have set the evaluateasexpression for the variable to true.

When i try to use this variable as a sql command, the error is:

```
"invalid syntax near the +"
```

(i believe this is the plus sign below the redactedcol3 below)

BTW, is property expressions the only place where you can evaluate a variable's value as you are developing? (expression builder).

This is how the variable displays in the message box in the script component:

```
"SELECT redactedcol1,redactedcol2,rtrim(" + "'" + @user::LocalPath + " + "'" + "+[redactedcol3]) AS Path FROM dbo.SF_redacted where id=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not *entirely* sure this is what you want, but I think it is:

```
"SELECT redactedcol1,redactedcol2,rtrim("
+ "'" 
+ @user::LocalPath 
+ "'" 
+ " + [redactedcol3]) AS Path FROM dbo.SF_redacted where id=1"
```

Note the removed extraneous plus sign and double-quote. (I find it helps when concatenating in SSIS to put each part on its own line.)

And I also recommend [BIDS Helper](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/), a free tool that includes a better (IMO) expression building GUI, as well as [Konesans' Expression Editor](http://expressioneditor.codeplex.com/) which is a like a mini-Intellisense workbench for expressions.

There's also a Variables window in SSIS Projects (View -> Other Windows -> Variables) where you can see the evaluated value of a variable expression.

Answer (score 0):

For others wondering why their expression is not evaluating...

http://www.sqlchicken.com/2012/02/ssis-expressions-not-evaluating-correctly/

Click on the Variable. Make sure "EvaluateAsExpression" is `True`